# Python - Parse HTML lists and create a JSON array out of it

Tags: python, html, json, parsing, lxml

Im creating a restful API using Flask and for one of its exposed methods im trying to parse an HTML that looks like this:

```
<li class="product some_product">
  <div class="product_wrap">
   <div class="basic_stat product_title">
    <a href="/product/type/title1">
     The Never Ending Story
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="basic_stat product_score score">
    <div class="score_w">
     100
    </div>
   </div>
```

And it repeats the same format for other 20 different titles. Im trying to create a json structure out of these that will look like

`[{"Title": "The Never Ending Story", "Score": "100"}...]` and so on....

For that, I am testing BeautifulSoup to navigate the html:

```
my_list = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> my_list.find_all("div", text=lambda text: text and "score_w" in text)
[]
```

Gives me an empty array, for example.

How can I filter only the lines (text) that I need, without any spaces at the start of each line? Is the only part of this that is giving me some headache....

like:

```
The Never Ending Story

100

Titanic

80

Jurassic World

70
```

I can manage afterwards with transforming into the JSON myself.

Im not sure if Im on the right path or should I try a totally different approach. Im thinking of getting the text values like that first, then create the dict or json should be a simple thing.

I really appreaciate your help

Comment: Just a warning to you, questions asking for broad advice are technically considered off-topic and are likely to be flagged as a result.

Comment: oops, sorry wasnt quite sure this would be considered "broad advice" actually im new to stackoverflow as a poster. I'll come back when I have tested further and closer to my objective then - sorry.

Comment: @geekiechic could you paste more HTML? I'd need to see the structure of several products to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys thank you for the help. I am new to SO as a poster so please flag if needed...

I was able to resolve this after some testing with Beautiful Soup like this:

I analyzed how to navigate the souped html first, then I extracted both the titles and the scores creating two separate lists

```
titles, scores = [],[]
for line in movies_html.findAll('a'):
    titles.append(line.getText(strip=True))

for line in movies_html.findAll('div', class_="basic_stat product_score"):
    scores.append(line.getText(strip=True))
```

# Then I Merged the Lists into a List of Dicts using zip

```
result= [ { "title": str(t), "score": int(s) } for t, s in zip(titles, scores) ]
```

# And finally I used the json module to dump into json format

```
 json = jsom.dumps(result, indent=2) 
 return json
```

Maybe there was a clean-er or more beautiful approach, but I dont think this is that ugly though?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#==========================================================

titles  = 'movies.html'

defaultDir  = 'C:\\Users\\geekiechic\\Documents\\'  ##  win
# defaultDir  = '/home/eli/Documents/'  ##  linux
##=========================================================

movies = []

with open((defaultDir + titles), 'r') as data:
    even = -1
    for line in data:
        if not line .lstrip() .startswith('<'):
            even += 1
            if even % 2 == 0:
                movies += ("{'Title': '%s" % line.strip())
            else:
                movies += ("', 'Score': '%s'}," % line.strip())

output  = '' .join(movies) .rstrip(',')
print('[' + output + ']')
```